# How to export Landsat Simple Composite output?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I want to extend the "Landsat Simple Composite" example by exporting the stuff inside a rectangle.

```
var geometry = 
/* color: #d63000 */
/* displayProperties: [
  {
    "type": "rectangle"
  }
] */
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-47.8334884033203, -0.5160872232277051],
      [-47.8334884033203, -0.6455132239753004],
      [-47.62577813720702, -0.6455132239753004],
      [-47.62577813720702, -0.5160872232277051]]], null, false);

// Composite 6 months of Landsat 8.

// Note that the input to simpleComposite is raw data.
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1');

// The asFloat parameter gives floating-point TOA output instead of
// the UINT8 outputs of the default simpleComposite().
var composite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: l8.filterDate('2015-1-1', '2015-7-1'),
  asFloat: true
});

// Pick a spot with lots of clouds.
Map.setCenter(-47.6735, -0.6344, 12);
// Display a composite with a band combination chosen from:
// https://landsat.usgs.gov/how-do-landsat-8-band-combinations-differ-landsat-7-or-landsat-5-satellite-data

Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B6', 'B5', 'B4'], max: [0.3, 0.4, 0.3]});

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: composite,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry
});
```

The lines for exporting the image are from https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting.  However, the .tif file, when opened, displays:

[image: Opened tif file]

In the browser is seen:
[image: code editor view]
where what is inside the red rectangle is the stuff I want to export.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a few different versions with your code but actually nothing is wrong with it.
You are trying to export a composite image with 11 bands as 1 GeoTIFF image. Meaning the image you are seeing with stripes is having information of 11 bands per pixel. You need to open this with a remote sensing or GIS program such as QGIS in order to visualize properly.
Here is my screenshot when I open your exported image with QGIS:

[image]

When you click on a pixel you can get the values for each band.

You can also play with the layer properties. Regarding your code if you wanna use the B6-B5-B4 for RGB here is the result:

[image]